# Ansible and "sudo su -"

Tags: automation, ansible

I have some machines where I log with the main account and after that I can execute "sudo su -" without a password if there is a need.
Do you know any way in Ansible to execute "sudo su -" after I log in to my primary account? Thanks in advance.

What I was trying in example 
play.yml:

```
---
- hosts: b1
  remote_user: user
  become: yes
  tasks:
     - name: who
       shell: whoami >> file.txt
```

Also added this to Ansible hosts file:

```
host ansible_ssh_host=7.7.7.7 ansible_become_method=su ansible_become_exe="sudo su -"
```

When I execute playbook with -k argument it asks for my pass, however, it doesn't become root later on.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overcomplicating this.

If the login user already has passwordless sudo, then just try this - strip the extra stuff off the host and use a simpler play.

> hostfile

```
b1 ansible_ssh_host=7.7.7.7
```

> playbook

```
---
- hosts: b1
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
     - name: who
       shell: whoami >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
- hosts: b1
  become: yes
  become_user: oracle
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
     - name: who
       command: /u01/app/oracle/OPatch/opatch lsinv
```

`ansible-playbook patch1.yml -i /Users/Desktop/AnsibleSCP/hosts.inv -k`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
- hosts: b1
  become: yes
  become_exe: "sudo su -"
  become_method: su
  tasks:
    ...
```